# Get DOM document of web page

Tags: c#, dom

I'm trying to retrieve the DOM document of a webpage and I can see all I require in the developer tool's inspector (F12)

```
public static string ScreenScrape(string url)
    {
        String returned = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            using (System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    returned = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return returned;
    }
```

I'm not managing to retrieve the data I require by using the code above. It seems like a lot of the webpage is being left out.

Can anyone offer any advice please?

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered to use `WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString(URL);`

Comment: yes.. same result :(